# Ajax still gets data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to find what's causing my code to still get data even if the query is false. It is a simple log in form using ajax.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit_login").click(function() {
    var username = $("input#username").val();
    if (username == "") {
       $('#error').html('Please Insert Your Email Address');    
       return false;
    }
    var password = $("input#password").val();
    if (password == "") {
       $('#error').html('Please Insert Your Password'); 
       return false;
    }
    var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password=' + password;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'login.php',
      data: dataString,
      dataType: "html",
      beforeSend: function(){ $("#submit_login").val('Connecting...');},
      success: function(data) {
      if (data == 0) {
      $('#error').html('Wrong Login Data')
      $("#submit_login").val('Sign in!');
        } else {
            $('#error').html('<b style="color:green;">you are logged. wait for redirection</b>');   
            document.location.href = 'private.php'; 
        }
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config2.php");
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
// username and password sent from Form
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
$password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password'])); 
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
if ($results)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $obj->id;
        echo $username;
}


}

?>
```

The thing is, every time an attempt to log in happens, it redirect me to private.php even the username and password are incorrect. This means that the login.php still gets data even though the query return is false or 0.

I'm having a hard time finding out what is causing this and hopefully you guys can help me out! cheers.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)`? I don't see any 0 printed in login.php.

Comment: You forgot to add semicolumn ';' at end of this code $('#error').html('Wrong Login Data')

Comment: @caCtus don't need a `0` because no data will still `==0` for example `console.log( '' == 0 ) //true`. This is just a really bad conditional test

Comment: NOT a very good login mechanism. In your PHP, you never output `0` (....data will NEVER be 0) and `dataType:"html"` should be `dataType:"text"` ... Try this: `console.log( "'" + data + "'" );`

Comment: @peterKA will try that one.

Answer (score -1):

If condition in login.php probably false. Should it be like this?? The variable $results always return 1 because you hold the query and not the results itself. Instead of $result, change to $obj.

```
if ($obj)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $obj->id;
    echo $username; 
}
```

Comment: True, but it still redirects me to private.php

Comment: I echo'd username so it returns a value.